# Match, copy & paste from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

i'm new to VBA excel. I'm planning to find the matched value from a database, and copy the data to another sheet. Below codes are works but it was stopped running after few times tries. Is my excel file corrupted ? Or code is wrong.

```
Sub match()
Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim searchlist As Range
    Dim rcell As Range, sValue As String
    Dim lcol As Long, cRow As Long
    Dim dRange As Range, sCell As Range
    Dim d As Long

    Set searchlist = Sheets("sheet2").Range("a5:a" & lastrow)

    Set dRange = Sheets("Database").Range("a1:a" & lastrow)
    For Each rcell In searchlist
        lcol = 1 

        For Each sCell In dRange
            If InStr(1, sCell.Value, rcell.Value) And Trim(rcell.Value) <> "" Then


                For d = 1 To 22
                rcell.Offset(0, lcol).Value = sCell.Offset(0, d).Value
                lcol = lcol + 1
             Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Define your last row using the specific sheet, not ActiveSheet; do Database and Sheet2 have the same number of rows?

Comment: On which line does it stop?

Comment: Hi @Cyril, both sheet2 and database have different number of rows. I changed the definition of lastrow based on your suggestion. it's works. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code:

```
If InStr(1, sCell.Value, rcell.Value) And Trim(rcell.Value) <> "" Then
```

to

```
If InStr(1, sCell.Value, rcell.Value) > 0 And Trim(rcell.Value) <> "" Then
```

Hope this help.